# Why do I get this error message: "undefined reference to `PerformChat(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)'"

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, chatscript

I am trying to compile my program that uses ChatScript libraries. This is my code inside a file named `main.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "common.h"

using namespace std;


char* output2;
unsigned int InitSystem(int argc,char* argv[]);
void InitStandalone();

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char * userID;
userID="one";


PerformChat("one",NULL,"hi",NULL,output2);

cout<<output2;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to include all the ChatScript libraries, also I know the `performChat` function is within `mainSystem.h` file that I have included it too(as you can see its in the line 218:  https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/SRC/mainSystem.h).

But after trying to compile my program by this command :

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp constructCode.cpp csocket.cpp dictionarySystem.cpp english.cpp evserver.cpp factSystem.cpp functionExecute.cpp infer.cpp jsmn.cpp json.cpp markSystem.cpp mongodb.cpp mysql.cpp os.cpp outputSystem.cpp patternSystem.cpp postgres.cpp privatesrc.cpp scriptCompile.cpp spellcheck.cpp systemVariables.cpp tagger.cpp testing.cpp textUtilities.cpp tokenSystem.cpp topicSystem.cpp userCache.cpp userSystem.cpp variableSystem.cpp -o myprogram
```

I got many of this errors!!

```
                                             ^
/tmp/ccuVtYkV.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `PerformChat(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)'
/tmp/cc6Mhc8u.o: In function `TestIf(char*, FunctionResult&, char*)':
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x9d5): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0xb62): undefined reference to `trace'
/tmp/cc6Mhc8u.o:constructCode.cpp:(.text+0xbab): more undefined references to `trace' follow
/tmp/cc6Mhc8u.o: In function `HandleIf(char*, char*, FunctionResult&)':
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0xd15): undefined reference to `always'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0xe75): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x1086): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x11c4): undefined reference to `trace'
/tmp/cc6Mhc8u.o: In function `HandleLoop(char*, char*, FunctionResult&)':
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x13ab): undefined reference to `trace'
constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x14a7): undefined reference to `trace'
/tmp/cc6Mhc8u.o:constructCode.cpp:(.text+0x298c): more undefined references to `trace' follow
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `fillAddr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned short, sockaddr_in&)':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x2320): undefined reference to `hostname'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `Client':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x37bf): undefined reference to `always'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x3840): undefined reference to `port'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x389d): undefined reference to `port'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x3af1): undefined reference to `port'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x3b4e): undefined reference to `port'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `RegressLoad(void*)':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x3f96): undefined reference to `revertBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x3fcb): undefined reference to `revertBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x401c): undefined reference to `revertBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x40b9): undefined reference to `port'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `LogChat(long, char*, char*, char*, int, char*, char*)':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4559): undefined reference to `version'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `LaunchClient(void*)':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4821): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `InternetServer()':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4a01): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4a1f): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4a38): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `ServerTransferDataToClient()':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x4a8d): undefined reference to `ourMainOutputBuffer'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `HandleTCPClient(void*)':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5454): undefined reference to `outputLength'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `GrabPort()':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5777): undefined reference to `interfaceKind[abi:cxx11]'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5799): undefined reference to `port'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x57c7): undefined reference to `port'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x57d6): undefined reference to `interfaceKind[abi:cxx11]'
/tmp/ccWaC4y6.o: In function `MainChatbotServer()':
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5940): undefined reference to `quitting'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5a7d): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5a83): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5a8e): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5aa1): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5afa): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5b1b): undefined reference to `ourMainOutputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5b3b): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5b43): undefined reference to `PerformChat(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5b5b): undefined reference to `Restart()'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5bb0): undefined reference to `ourMainInputBuffer'
csocket.cpp:(.text+0x5bd6): undefined reference to `ourMainOutputBuffer'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `ClearWhereInSentence()':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `documentMode'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `AllocateWhereInSentence(WORDENTRY*)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x5ce): undefined reference to `documentMode'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `UseDictionaryFile(char*)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0xefc): undefined reference to `language'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0xf1f): undefined reference to `language'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0xf3a): undefined reference to `language'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `ReadForeignPosTags(char*)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x10a0): undefined reference to `readBuffer'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x10d9): undefined reference to `readBuffer'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `BuildDictionary(char*)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x1402): undefined reference to `language'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x157f): undefined reference to `language'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x165c): undefined reference to `users'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x16ba): undefined reference to `CreateSystem()'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `StoreWord(char*, unsigned long long)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x2915): undefined reference to `server'
/tmp/ccwtMWsK.o: In function `ShowStats(bool)':
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x31bb): undefined reference to `volleyStartTime'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x31c8): undefined reference to `inputSentenceCount'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x31d2): undefined reference to `inputSentenceCount'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x322b): undefined reference to `tokenCount'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x3266): undefined reference to `tokenCount'
dictionarySystem.cpp:(.text+0x326c): undefined reference to `inputSentenceCount'
```

Comment: please show with which arguments you are calling the compiler. Seems as if the object file providing the implementation of `PerformChat` is not available to the compiler.

Comment: @StephanLechner: I edited my post

Comment: So which part of **This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options** is unclear?

Comment: @n.m.: I did it but got many new errors!

Comment: I did #include all the .h files as you can see and tried to compile and link all together as you can see above, but I got many `undefiend reference` errors again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could compile my program with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp constructCode.cpp duktape/duktape.cpp evserver.cpp csocket.cpp cs_ev.c dictionarySystem.cpp englishTagger.cpp factSystem.cpp json.cpp functionExecute.cpp english.cpp infer.cpp javascript.cpp jsmn.cpp markSystem.cpp mysql.cpp mongodb.cpp os.cpp outputSystem.cpp patternSystem.cpp postgres.cpp privatesrc.cpp scriptCompile.cpp spellcheck.cpp secure.cpp systemVariables.cpp tagger.cpp testing.cpp textUtilities.cpp tokenSystem.cpp topicSystem.cpp userCache.cpp userSystem.cpp variableSystem.cpp mainSystem.cpp -o myapp -L/usr/lib64 -lrt -lcurl -pthread -Ievserver -DDISCARDSERVER=1 -DDISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -DDISCARDMONGO=1 -DDISCARDMYSQL=1 -DEVSERVER=1 -DEVSERVER_FORK=1
```

I found the options from my makefile and added them at the end of my command as you can see (after -o myapp)

Answer (score 2):

With `g++ -0 test test.cpp`, you tell the compiler to compile and link the program, but you miss to tell the compiler where to find the necessary libraries for linking.

If you write `g++ -o test.o -c test.cpp`, then the compiler will just compile, not link, and you should get a valid `test.o` object file.

Then, you can link everything together. For that, load down a binary from your GIT repository; I suppose it's the [LinuxChatScript64](https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/BINARIES/LinuxChatScript64) file. Place the file, let's say, in the same directory where your `.cpp`-file resides.

Then, link with:

```
g++ -o myprogram test.o LinuxChatScript64
```

Hope it works. Good luck!

Comment: LinuxChatScript64:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
LinuxChatScript64: In function `main':
(.text+0x17f0e2): multiple definition of `main'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

Comment: LinuxChatScript64:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
LinuxChatScript64: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
LinuxChatScript64: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'

Comment: LinuxChatScript64:(.data+0x7c70): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in LinuxChatScript64(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I did what you said and got this error messages!
Why did you say I use LinuxChatScript64 in last command?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile with just the header (.h) files. The header files provide the signatures, but the implementations are in object (.o) files, and need to be linked by the compiler.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Likely you did download the .o files. They should be part of the ChatScript library. So I think what you're missing is the proper build flags to include the .o files in the build. I see some .sln (Windows) or make instructions in ChatScript's github page. You may just have to try to follow more exact directions.

Comment: I used a new command for compile and edited my post. did I do it wrong?